# Parse Timestamp into readable format (Android)

Tags: java, android, timestamp, simpledateformat

I need to convert the following timestamp

```
 String s = "08-12-2014 05:00:00"

 to a readable format like "Today 5am"
```

Please kindly suggest how i can do it or libaries that i can use.

btw here what i tried

```
      String ago = hourly.getHour(j).time() ;
            SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",  Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date d = inputFormat.parse(ago);
            SimpleDateFormat outputFormat=   new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm  a");
```

Comment: i guess you are looking for this.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeDateTimeString%28android.content.Context,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20int%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",  Locale.ENGLISH);
     SimpleDateFormat outputFormat=   new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm  a");

    try {
        Date oneWayTripDate = inputFormat.parse(datedata);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
String  datetime=    outputFormat.format(oneWayTripDate);
}
```